# Prove $\lim_{x\rightarrow -3} 1-4x=13$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, proof-verification, epsilon-delta

### Problem

Prove $$\lim_{x\rightarrow -3} 1-4x=13$$

Using $\delta, \epsilon$ definiton of limits.

### Attempt to solve

I can use $\delta ,\epsilon$ definition of limit. If i can show

$$ |x-a| < \delta \implies |f(x)-L| < \epsilon$$

It implies limit exists according to $\delta, \epsilon$ definition of limits.

$$ |x-(-3)|< \delta \implies |1-4x-13|< \epsilon $$
$$ |1-4x-13|< \epsilon \iff |-4x-12| < \epsilon \iff |4x+12|< \epsilon $$
$$ |x-(-3)|< \delta \iff |x+3| < \delta $$
$$ \text{let }  \delta = \epsilon/4$$
$$ |x+3| < \delta \implies |x+3|<\epsilon/4 \implies$$
$$ 4|x+3|<\epsilon \implies $$
$$ |4(x+3)|< \epsilon \implies $$
$$ |4x+12| < \epsilon $$

$$\tag*{$\square$}$$

I would like to have some feedback if my solution looks correct or not.

Comment: What is your question? Your steps look good.

Comment: Your solution is fine.

Comment: @Gibbs My question is that does my logic and proof seem correct ? but you seem to answer this already, thanks !

Comment: @Tuki it is ok. When you post something, make sure to write a question explicitly. Otherwise it may be closed because it is not clear what you are asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your solution is correct.